# On the Kenwood TM-D710, what is the "D" on the B band?

Tags: kenwood

I can explain almost every part of the Kenwood TM-D710(G) display *except* the letter "D" that appears on the second line of the B band next to the power level. I've poured over the manual and can't find any reference to what that indicates. I've only seen it on the B band, and I haven't seen any setting that turns it off.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual, it says "Appears while using the External data band", and all of the images of the display in the manual show it only appearing on the B band.

However, menu setting (according to the manual, again) 517 allows you to set how the external TNC data band setup is defined (A band, B band, Tx on A and Rx on B, or Tx on B, Rx on A).

I suggest you give the whole manual a thorough read-through - many radios that have APRS and built-in TNCs have many many settings that can be overwhelming. I have a Yaesu FT-2DR that I have to check the manual for regularly just because I forget which settings are kept where ...

I hope this is useful - I am not really sure that it is, as I am not familiar with that specific radio, and only downloaded the manual to see what it said in there.

Comment: Looks like you're right, when I change the External Data Band (option 918 on the 710G), it moves that "D". I got that confused with the Internal Data Band (option 930 on the 710G), which is indicated with a "highlighted D" as shown in the screenshot in the A band to the right of 144.390. Thanks for tracking that down!